# How do we Embed Fonts in Visualforce Pages rendered as PDF?

Tags: apex, visualforce, html, pdf, font

We have some Visualforce pages that are rendered as PDF. The PDF is being printed by a Third Party Printing Company.

The font we are using is either Sans-serif or Arial Unicode MS. We need to embed these fonts in the PDF so that there is no problem with the printing company due to missing fonts and whatnot. From what I saw on the internet, we can use content type for this, but it didn't work for me. Do we have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

No. Server-side PDF generation does not support custom fonts. This is specified in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_supported_fonts.htm).

> Web fonts aren’t supported when the page is rendered as a PDF file. You can use web fonts in your Visualforce pages when they’re rendered normally.

Comment: But these are not custom fonts. These fonts are supported by salesforce. I need to embed them in the PDF.

Comment: @vedantgupta You can't embed fonts. If you style the elements using the normal names (e.g. `sans-serif`) it should work correctly.